# Google Play Music not playing music

Tags: google-play-music

I have a Google Play Music subscription. It works everywhere I tried except at my home. When I try to play a song from a play list I'm getting:

"Couldn't play *name*. Skipped ahead."

[image: "Couldn't play... Skipped ahead."]

After a few songs being skipped a message appears that reads:

"Can't reach Google Play. Reload the page and try again."

[image: "Can't reach Google Play. Reload the page and try again."]

When this happening in the browser console there are a lot of 403 errors:

[image: browser console showing HTTP 403 errors]

These are requests to https://redirector.gvt1.com/videoplayback and they have googleusercontent.com in the query string.

The 403 response from these requests look like this:

[image: 403 response]

It's just Google Play Music that is not working. Everything else is working fine, and there are 5 people in the household using internet on daily basis - no other complaints.

What is interesting, is that as soon as I connect my computer to a VPN, Google Music starts working.

Can any one suggest why I might be having this problem? I'm not living in China.

Comment: Just wanted to open a question about the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @arieljannai, no.